# type argument inference for interfaces and types without functions

Tags: typescript, generics

In this example, I want the `property` property in expression `itemKV1` to constrain itself so it when the `property` is `age`, the `value` can only be a type of `number`.

Any ideas on how to do something like this?

I know how to do this with the generics in functions because it provides `type argument inference`, as documented [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#hello-world-of-generics).

The issue is that I cannot infer the `property` to constrain the `value`. I can't figure out a way to do this with an interface or a type.

```js
interface Item {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

// Where can I add a generic for `keyof T`?
type KV<T> = { property: keyof T; value: T[keyof T] };

// I want value to be of type `number`, not `string | number`
// this should show an error, but doesn't.
const itemKV1: KV<Item> = {
  property: "age",
  value: "not a number!"
};

// This should not error and doesn't.
const itemKV2: KV<Item> = {
  property: "age",
  value: 82
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not generally possible to both infer and constrain the type of a variable. You  either specify the type in an annotation or you let the compiler infer it based on assignment.

For your particular case though, there is another solution to get an error on the assignment you want. You can generate a union of all possible `property`/ `value` combinations as a union.

```
interface Item {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

// Where can I add a generic for `keyof T`?
type KV<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: { property: P; value: T[P] };
}[keyof T]

// KV<Item> =  
//   | { property: "id"; value: string; }
//   | { property: "name"; value: string; }
//   | { property: "age"; value: number; }
// Error value is not numebr 
const itemKV1: KV<Item> = {
  property: "age",
  value: "not a number!"
};

// ok
const itemKV2: KV<Item> = {
  property: "age",
  value: 82
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=26&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4FgBQyywAJgFzIDOYUoA5gNwFEhwYQXW0iPPJx0OyEAFcMAI2hN8AXwIEA9AuQB1ABbQUCOCDT8SJfskEhowBMhgB7KMgAGAawgBPKzGQAVOwH4CYZwAOKADSAGoAPB4AfMgAvDh8RADaAArEuk6u7h4AuhTYyAFQVkFQ-hQpDMgAbnAANiJCHqk5yDLSMkmZbp458vhKyGHh6BAYMfHIispEAD44hcWl5cgARKSrVbUNQlz0VXIDM8jzBUUl0CurrOybNfWNnDT7bdNEJwvny84UqwIQd22j2EYkkUAObwAolBirYgShgJRhFYwCD2OJbAQEFYQNRiJgwgBGCjDUbjOIJQiLC5lH5rf6rAA0fHhvxAKKMogk0AAhKsCO1+oMrA4sTi8cACaEAEwkiJkiaUohfS50v6CJksh5CAAc0oFDCAA)

**NOTE**: `itemKV1.value` will still be of type `string | number` unless you narrow it based on the `property` field. If you want the final type of the variable to be based on the assignment but  constrained you will need a function:

```
function property<T>() {
    return function <TKV extends KV<T>>(o: TKV) {
        return o 
    }
}

// ok
// const itemKV2: {
//     property: "age";
//     value: number;
// }
const itemKV2 = property<Item>()({
    property: "age",
    value: 82
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=26&ssc=4&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4FgBQyywAJgFzIDOYUoA5gNwFEhwYQXW0iPPJx0OyEAFcMAI2hN8AXwIEA9AuQB1ABbQUCOCDT8SJfskEhowBMhgB7KMgAGAawgBPKzGQAVOwH4CYZwAOKADSAGoAPB4AfMgAvDh8RADaAArEuk6u7h4AuhTYyAFQVkFQ-hQpDMgAbnAANiJCHqk5yDLSMkmZbp458vgwIiAIYMBWukUl0P6RUQAUAJQJhETIUBBgIlC6g8Oj48iRYcgQAB6QICSUyGGz81YUHmFLeCurq+ub28hWyIltBDk+EUyisDhByAQ42oxEwYQATPkIe9JqVysgAEQCCAY6RKd41eqNCiiCRSCFAqEgGHAOGheFxQrFNHOcLoCAYeYLOavFHM6bOChYwQYgA0-1qDSEAA54YCFgwgA)